# Django IntegrityError Duplicate entry on Foreignkey

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am having a subtle error with a duplicate key integrity error on django with a set of foreignkey relations.

I have the following function:

```
def update_relationship(actor, action, status, target):
  existing = Relation.objects.filter(actor=actor, target=target)

  # If this relation is 'on', turn it off
  if Relation.objects.filter(actor=actor, target=target, status=status):
    Relation.objects.filter(actor=actor, target=target).update(status="")
  # If this relationship is not on, turn it on
  else:
    created = True
    if existing:
      existing.update(status=status)
    else:
      Relation.objects.create(actor=actor, target=target, status=status)
```

As you can see, I am testing to see if the relationship exists already in the database and then updating it if it does exist and creating a new row if it does not.  However, it seems under some conditions that I can't reproduce, Django is giving me a duplicate key error, even for conditions where, as far as I can tell, there is only one instance of that.

For reference, here is the the model definition:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
  Status = Choices(('L', 'Like', 'Like'), 
                   ('D', 'Dislike', 'Dislike'), 
                   ('S', 'Save', 'Save'))
  actor     = models.ForeignKey('members.Member', related_name='relations')
  target    = models.ForeignKey('members.Member', related_name='reverse_relations')
  status    = models.CharField(choices=Status, max_length=10)
  created   = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)

  notified        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  notified_mutual = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('actor', 'target'),)
    ordering = ('created',)
    verbose_name = 'Relation'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Relations'
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, right expression to check for [existence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists) is:

```
existing = Relation.objects.filter(actor=actor, target=target).exists()
```

But the djano way to write your sentences is with [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method, is that method that you are looking for:

```
Relation.objects.get_or_create(actor=actor, target=target, 
                                 defaults={ 'status':status }
                              )
```

Or, for your case, something like:

```
r, _ = Relation.objects.get_or_create(actor=actor, target=target )
r.status = '' if r.status == 'on' else status
r.save()
```

Comment: It'd be kind of nice if Django had an update_or_create method but this seems to be a better approach than my method.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Oddly this is still happening even with the Django get_or_create. I thought perhaps it was due to not setting defaults but even with defaults it still happens.